# WordPress Settings API, Implementing Tabs On Custom Menu Page

Tags: menus, settings-api, options

I've been following the WordPress Settings API tutorial series of this guy:

http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/the-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-settings-api-part-1/

So far, I've been successful at doing the basic thing. Now, when implementing tab, I'm facing problem.

Problem 1: The Tabs are not working. All the fields are being displayed on both the tabs. Section 1, should be displayed on Tab One and Section 2 on Tab Two.

Problem 2: Option 2 is not being saved. It was working fine before implementing tabs.

[image]

[image]

Code:

```
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* Add Menu Page */
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */ 

function add_my_menu() {
    add_menu_page (
        'Page Title', // page title 
        'Menu Title', // menu title
        'manage_options', // capability
        'my-menu-slug',  // menu-slug
        'my_menu_page',   // function that will render its output
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/ico/theme-option-menu-icon.png'   // link to the icon that will be displayed in the sidebar
        //$position,    // position of the menu option
    );
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_my_menu');
function my_menu_page() {
        ?>
        <?php  
        if( isset( $_GET[ 'tab' ] ) ) {  
            $active_tab = $_GET[ 'tab' ];  
        } else {
            $active_tab = 'tab_one';
        }
        ?>  
        <div class="wrap">
            <h2>Menu Page Title</h2>
            <div class="description">This is description of the page.</div>
            <?php settings_errors(); ?> 

            <h2 class="nav-tab-wrapper">  
                <a href="?page=my-menu-slug&tab=tab_one" class="nav-tab <?php echo $active_tab == 'tab_one' ? 'nav-tab-active' : ''; ?>">Tab One</a>  
                <a href="?page=my-menu-slug&tab=tab_two" class="nav-tab <?php echo $active_tab == 'tab_two' ? 'nav-tab-active' : ''; ?>">Tab Two</a>  
            </h2>  

            <form method="post" action="options.php"> 
            <?php
                if( $active_tab == 'tab_one' ) {  

                    settings_fields( 'setting-group-1' );
                    do_settings_sections( 'my-menu-slug' );

                } elseif( $active_tab == 'tab_two' )  {

                    settings_fields( 'setting-group-2' );
                    do_settings_sections( 'my-menu-slug' );

                }
            ?>

                <?php submit_button(); ?> 
            </form> 

        </div>
        <?php
}

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* Setting Sections And Fields */
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */ 

function sandbox_initialize_theme_options() {  
    add_settings_section(  
        'page_1_section',         // ID used to identify this section and with which to register options  
        'Section 1',                  // Title to be displayed on the administration page  
        'page_1_section_callback', // Callback used to render the description of the section  
        'my-menu-slug'                           // Page on which to add this section of options  

    );

    add_settings_section(  
        'page_2_section',         // ID used to identify this section and with which to register options  
        'Section 2',                  // Title to be displayed on the administration page  
        'page_2_section_callback', // Callback used to render the description of the section  
        'my-menu-slug'                           // Page on which to add this section of options  
    );

    /* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /* Option 1 */
    /* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */ 

    add_settings_field (   
        'option_1',                      // ID used to identify the field throughout the theme  
        'Option 1',                           // The label to the left of the option interface element  
        'option_1_callback',   // The name of the function responsible for rendering the option interface  
        'my-menu-slug',                          // The page on which this option will be displayed  
        'page_1_section',         // The name of the section to which this field belongs  
        array(                              // The array of arguments to pass to the callback. In this case, just a description.  
            'This is the description of the option 1',
        )  
    );  
    register_setting(  
        //~ 'my-menu-slug',  
        'setting-group-1',  
        'option_1'  
    );

    /* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /* Option 2 */
    /* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */     

    add_settings_field (   
        'option_2',  // ID -- ID used to identify the field throughout the theme  
        'Option 2', // LABEL -- The label to the left of the option interface element  
        'option_2_callback', // CALLBACK FUNCTION -- The name of the function responsible for rendering the option interface  
        'my-menu-slug', // MENU PAGE SLUG -- The page on which this option will be displayed  
        'page_2_section', // SECTION ID -- The name of the section to which this field belongs  
        array( // The array of arguments to pass to the callback. In this case, just a description.  
            'This is the description of the option 2', // DESCRIPTION -- The description of the field.
        )  
    );
    register_setting(  
        'setting-group-2',  
        'option_2'  
    );

} // function sandbox_initialize_theme_options
add_action('admin_init', 'sandbox_initialize_theme_options');

function page_1_section_callback() {  
    echo '<p>Section Description here</p>';  
} // function page_1_section_callback
function page_2_section_callback() {  
    echo '<p>Section Description here</p>';  
} // function page_1_section_callback

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* Field Callbacks */
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */ 

function option_1_callback($args) {  
    ?>
    <input type="text" id="option_1" class="option_1" name="option_1" value="<?php echo get_option('option_1') ?>">
    <p class="description option_1"> <?php echo $args[0] ?> </p>
    <?php      
} // end sandbox_toggle_header_callback  

function option_2_callback($args) {  
    ?>
    <textarea id="option_2" class="option_2" name="option_2" rows="5" cols="50"><?php echo get_option('option_2') ?></textarea>
    <p class="description option_2"> <?php echo $args[0] ?> </p>
    <?php      
} // end sandbox_toggle_header_callback
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the settings API, but from first glance it appears all of your fields belong to a single settings section, which you output in both tabs.

Comment: @Milo I got it working, but I would say that WordPress Settings API is very confusing to understand. Also, it has nearly zero official documentation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is how I do it, beware, post is extensive.

```
/* Add Menus
-----------------------------------------------------------------*/
add_action('admin_menu', 'ch_essentials_admin');
function ch_essentials_admin() {
    /* Base Menu */
    add_menu_page(
    'Essentials Theme',
    'Essentials Theme',
    'manage_options',
    'ch-essentials-options',
    'ch_essentials_index');
}
```

Now for my settings fields, extra fields removed, just as an example.

This is for 'Front Page Settings' and 'Front Page Tab'

```
add_action('admin_init', 'ch_essentials_options');
function ch_essentials_options() { 

/* Front Page Options Section */
add_settings_section( 
    'ch_essentials_front_page',
    'Essentials Front Page Options',
    'ch_essentials_front_page_callback',
    'ch_essentials_front_page_option'
);

add_settings_field(  
    'featured_post',                      
    'Featured Post',               
    'ch_essentials_featured_post_callback',   
    'ch_essentials_front_page_option',                     
    'ch_essentials_front_page'
);
```

This is for my header options, which is the tab 'header options'

```
/* Header Options Section */
add_settings_section( 
    'ch_essentials_header',
    'Essentials Header Options',
    'ch_essentials_header_callback',
    'ch_essentials_header_option'
);

add_settings_field(  
    'header_type',                      
    'Header Type',               
    'ch_essentials_textbox_callback',   
    'ch_essentials_header_option',                     
    'ch_essentials_header',
    array(
        'header_type' 
    ) 
);
```

Register Settings

```
register_setting('ch_essentials_front_page_option', 'ch_essentials_front_page_option');
register_setting('ch_essentials_header_option', 'ch_essentials_header_option');
```

All of these are wrapped in one function, then done with an admin_init

```
/* Options
-----------------------------------------------------------------*/
add_action('admin_init', 'ch_essentials_options');
function ch_essentials_options() { 
    /* Code Shown above */
}
```

Call Backs:

```
/* Call Backs
-----------------------------------------------------------------*/
function ch_essentials_front_page_callback() { 
    echo '<p>Front Page Display Options:</p>'; 
}
function ch_essentials_header_callback() { 
    echo '<p>Header Display Options:</p>'; 
}
function ch_essentials_textbox_callback($args) { 
     
    $options = get_option('ch_essentials_header_option'); 
    
    echo '<input type="text" id="'  . $args[0] . '" name="ch_essentials_header_option['  . $args[0] . ']" value="' . $options[''  . $args[0] . ''] . '"></input>';
     
}
function ch_essentials_featured_post_callback($args) { 
     
    $options = get_option('ch_essentials_front_page_option'); 
    
    query_posts( $args );
    
    
    echo '<select id="featured_post" name="ch_essentials_front_page_option[featured_post]">';
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    
        $selected = selected($options['featured_post'], get_the_id(), false);
        printf('<option value="%s" %s>%s</option>', get_the_id(), $selected, get_the_title());
        
    endwhile;
    echo '</select>';
     
     
}
```

**Now this is the display part, with the tabs..**

If you have your settings sections and fields done exactly like this, then you will be able to do the tabs flawlessly.

```
/* Display Page
-----------------------------------------------------------------*/
function ch_essentials_index() {
?>
    <div class="wrap">  
        <div id="icon-themes" class="icon32"></div>  
        <h2>Essentials Theme Options</h2>  
        <?php settings_errors(); ?>  
        
        <?php  
                $active_tab = isset( $_GET[ 'tab' ] ) ? $_GET[ 'tab' ] : 'front_page_options';  
        ?>  
          
        <h2 class="nav-tab-wrapper">  
            <a href="?page=ch-essentials-options&tab=front_page_options" class="nav-tab <?php echo $active_tab == 'front_page_options' ? 'nav-tab-active' : ''; ?>">Front Page Options</a>  
            <a href="?page=ch-essentials-options&tab=header_options" class="nav-tab <?php echo $active_tab == 'header_options' ? 'nav-tab-active' : ''; ?>">Header Options</a>  
        </h2>  
          
        
        <form method="post" action="options.php">  
        
            <?php 
            if( $active_tab == 'front_page_options' ) {  
                settings_fields( 'ch_essentials_front_page_option' );
                do_settings_sections( 'ch_essentials_front_page_option' ); 
            } else if( $active_tab == 'header_options' ) {
                settings_fields( 'ch_essentials_header_option' );
                do_settings_sections( 'ch_essentials_header_option' ); 
                
            }
            ?>             
            <?php submit_button(); ?>  
        </form> 
  
    </div> 
<?php
}
```

-----EDIT-----

and I did notice in your post that you have 'elseif' and not 'else if' on your actual display page on the tab section

Comment: This was pretty useful for me. I was having trouble converting a single page to a tab page. The only things I added were an empty() check on the $option array for each input field. Otherwise, I was getting an error when the value was not set. I also added a a third argument to register_settings(). It takes an optional array to setup things like sanitization. Overall, this was a very good post with quality code.

Comment: why is the word 'options' plural in the template, but singular in the `add_settings_field`?

Answer (score 2):

Coding like this worked for me:

```
<?php 

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* Add Menu Page */
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */ 

function add_my_menu() {
    add_menu_page (
        'Page Title', // page title 
        'Menu Title', // menu title
        'manage_options', // capability
        'my-menu-slug',  // menu-slug
        'my_menu_page',   // function that will render its output
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/ico/theme-option-menu-icon.png'   // link to the icon that will be displayed in the sidebar
        //$position,    // position of the menu option
    );
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_my_menu');

function my_menu_page() {
        ?>
        <?php  
        if( isset( $_GET[ 'tab' ] ) ) {  
            $active_tab = $_GET[ 'tab' ];  
        } else {
            $active_tab = 'tab_one';
        }
        ?>  
        <div class="wrap">
            <h2>Menu Page Title</h2>
            <div class="description">This is description of the page.</div>
            <?php settings_errors(); ?> 

            <h2 class="nav-tab-wrapper">  
                <a href="?page=my-menu-slug&tab=tab_one" class="nav-tab <?php echo $active_tab == 'tab_one' ? 'nav-tab-active' : ''; ?>">Tab One</a>  
                <a href="?page=my-menu-slug&tab=tab_two" class="nav-tab <?php echo $active_tab == 'tab_two' ? 'nav-tab-active' : ''; ?>">Tab Two</a>  
            </h2>  

            <form method="post" action="options.php"> 
            <?php
                if( $active_tab == 'tab_one' ) {  

                    settings_fields( 'setting-group-1' );
                    do_settings_sections( 'my-menu-slug-1' );

                } else if( $active_tab == 'tab_two' )  {

                    settings_fields( 'setting-group-2' );
                    do_settings_sections( 'my-menu-slug-2' );

                }
            ?>

                <?php submit_button(); ?> 
            </form> 

        </div>
        <?php
}

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* Setting Sections And Fields */
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */ 

function sandbox_initialize_theme_options() {  
    add_settings_section(  
        'page_1_section',         // ID used to identify this section and with which to register options  
        'Section 1',                  // Title to be displayed on the administration page  
        'page_1_section_callback', // Callback used to render the description of the section  
        'my-menu-slug-1'                           // Page on which to add this section of options  

    );

    add_settings_section(  
        'page_2_section',         // ID used to identify this section and with which to register options  
        'Section 2',                  // Title to be displayed on the administration page  
        'page_2_section_callback', // Callback used to render the description of the section  
        'my-menu-slug-2'                           // Page on which to add this section of options  
    );

    /* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /* Option 1 */
    /* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */ 

    add_settings_field (   
        'option_1',                      // ID used to identify the field throughout the theme  
        'Option 1',                           // The label to the left of the option interface element  
        'option_1_callback',   // The name of the function responsible for rendering the option interface  
        'my-menu-slug-1',                          // The page on which this option will be displayed  
        'page_1_section',         // The name of the section to which this field belongs  
        array(                              // The array of arguments to pass to the callback. In this case, just a description.  
            'This is the description of the option 1',
        )  
    );  
    register_setting(  
        //~ 'my-menu-slug',  
        'setting-group-1',  
        'option_1'  
    );

    /* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /* Option 2 */
    /* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */     

    add_settings_field (   
        'option_2',  // ID -- ID used to identify the field throughout the theme  
        'Option 2', // LABEL -- The label to the left of the option interface element  
        'option_2_callback', // CALLBACK FUNCTION -- The name of the function responsible for rendering the option interface  
        'my-menu-slug-2', // MENU PAGE SLUG -- The page on which this option will be displayed  
        'page_2_section', // SECTION ID -- The name of the section to which this field belongs  
        array( // The array of arguments to pass to the callback. In this case, just a description.  
            'This is the description of the option 2', // DESCRIPTION -- The description of the field.
        )  
    );
    register_setting(  
        'setting-group-2',  
        'option_2'  
    );

} // function sandbox_initialize_theme_options
add_action('admin_init', 'sandbox_initialize_theme_options');

function page_1_section_callback() {  
    echo '<p>Section Description here</p>';  
} // function page_1_section_callback
function page_2_section_callback() {  
    echo '<p>Section Description here</p>';  
} // function page_1_section_callback

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* Field Callbacks */
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */ 

function option_1_callback($args) {  
    ?>
    <input type="text" id="option_1" class="option_1" name="option_1" value="<?php echo get_option('option_1') ?>">
    <p class="description option_1"> <?php echo $args[0] ?> </p>
    <?php      
} // end sandbox_toggle_header_callback  

function option_2_callback($args) {  
    ?>
    <textarea id="option_2" class="option_2" name="option_2" rows="5" cols="50"><?php echo get_option('option_2') ?></textarea>
    <p class="description option_2"> <?php echo $args[0] ?> </p>
    <?php      
} // end sandbox_toggle_header_callback  

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action="options.php"> 

    <?php
        if( $active_tab == 'tab_one' ) {  

            settings_fields( 'setting-group-1' );
            do_settings_sections( 'my-menu-slug-1' );

        } elseif( $active_tab == 'tab_two' )  {

            settings_fields( 'setting-group-2' );
            do_settings_sections( 'my-menu-slug-1' );

        }
    ?>
```

Change the `my-menu-slug` to `my-menu-slug-1` and `my-menu-slug-2`