# Theme-Config tab in admin Pannel?

Tags: functions, customization, themes

Sorry, for my broke english. There are few questions that I'd want to ask that got me quite confuse. I will try to phrase and describe my question the best way I could.

Starting with a bit of background.

I've create a basic theme on wordpress by hardcoding the structure and style with HTML, CSS & JS, I wrote some basic Javascript to do some translation and googlemap API stuff and hooking them into function.php. Basically most of the front-end works fine. Moving to the backend. As i've download few themes from wordpress.org. I saw some of theme got a theme-tab on the left sidebar in the admin pannel. Which enable users to change some element inside the theme(e.g. title, text or pictures)

Here comes the questions

1.) Does these kind of "theme tab" classify as plugins? if not what is it call?

2.) I'd want to try and create a theme tab which enable me to change some of the element in HTML (e.g. text or pictures), CSS (e.g. font-size, change background-image from upload media), JS (e.g. google-map lat & long, content of infowindow). Basiclly I would want my hardcode theme to be a REAL wordpress theme that enable users to change from the backend instead of looking through all the HTML or JS code.  Where should i start looking at? any learning resouces that would fit the criteria that i've mention above? Right now the difficulty that I'm facing is I dont even know what to search for in google in order to narrow down the result that fits me? admin-panel? theme-tab? backend changing JS?

3.) If i want to create a custom single.php page for a specific category of  post, is that possible?

Thats it for all my questions.

Many Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's not classified as plugins. It's also not a WordPress glossary and often called: *Tabs* which are built on **[Settings API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API)** and some tricks with `$_GET` request.
2. There're many [Q&As](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=settings+api), [references](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) you can learn from. [This topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/127493/wordpress-settings-api-implementing-tabs-on-custom-menu-page) seems to be the most relevant one for you.
3. Yes, you can do it with [`template_include`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) filter. These [Q&As](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=template_include) may be helpful too.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm looking for , thank you and really appreciate for the answers :D